# Python Request: Uable to get Cookie and Session Info

Tags: python, session, cookies

I am trying to get JSON data from [this](http://steamcommunity.com/market/recent?currency=1) URL. I also need to retrieve Cookies which contains `sessionId`. If you visit URL in chrome then you can see cookies contain a key `sessionId`. Below is my Code:

```
import requests
import json

url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/market/recent?currency=1'
session = requests.session()
r = session.get(url)
print(r.cookies) #it returns empty
data = r.text
json = json.loads(data)
```

Comment: I don't see any cookies when I see from Chrome. May be you are logged in?

Comment: Ah.. wait let me recheck

Comment: That URL sets no cookies. No Set-Cookie header is being transferred. If you see a session cookie, then that was set *on a different URL*.

Comment: Pretty much true. I checked without login on different URL and found no Cookie.

Comment: You can use, in this case, `r.json()` instead parse response into JSON.